# Разница между cUrl и Ajax

Tags: ajax, http, curl

Подскажите в чём разница между этими технологиями?

Понятно, что одна выполняется на сервере вторая на клиенте, но по факту и та и та технология используют http, как протокол и соответственно ответы должны приходить одинаковые. Но если мы отправили запрос cUrl на адрес example.com/get/json, то Curl вернёт данные а для ajax необходимо открывать CORS.

Какая технология проверки клиент это или сервер? И на каком этапе происходит проверка?

Comment: В чем разница между паровозом и подводной лодкой? Понятно, что одна плавает под водой, а второй по рельсам ездит, но по факту и та и та технология использует дизель, как топливо и соответственно пассажиры должны приезжать одинаковые.

Comment: @Darth Разница между паровозом и подлодкой в том, что паровоз приезжает на Ж/Д вокзал, а подводка приезжает на мор. вокзал. Они обслуживаются разными органами. А запросы http протокола обслуживает один сервер. И не понятно на каком этапе он определяет, где клиент отправил запрос, а где - нет

Comment: С помощью cUrl можно послать запрос на сервер, который нельзя будет отличить от посланного клиентом ajax запроса

Comment: @Darth Вот, а как сервер это определяет. По HTTP заголовкам, или на уровне  TCP/IP ? Получается Curl соединяется с сервером на уровень ниже?

Comment: у вас в голове путаница. почитайте на вики статьи про модель OSI, программу cUrl и технологию AJAX. Вообще да, запросы от cUrl и сделанные с помощью AJAX можно вычислить с помощью заголовков, но cUrl предоставляет неограниченные возможности по их подделке

Comment: @Darth я в принципе с OSI немного знаком, и про [Curl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) и (ajax)[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX] читал. И всё равно не понимаю нюанс. Тут даже дело не в CUrl, а можно взять PostMan. И там будет закрыт access-control-allow-origin то мы всё равно данные получим, а аяксом - нет

Comment: Вот как эта проверка происходит и не понятно. Если он по http заголовкам проверяет, то их можно поменять.

Comment: Вам нужно переформулировать вопрос. Я так понял, вы посылаете кросдоменный ajax запрос и не получаете данных? В данном случае проблема не в сервере, а в браузере - он данные получает, но из за отсутствия CORS не отдает их вам. Вам нужно переписать код серверной части, чтоб данные оттуда уходили с правильными заголовками

Comment: @ Darth Да, нет, просто хочу немного глубже понимать как работают (под капотом ) технология ajax и Curl/postman не важно. 
Как apache и nginx понимают где данные можно отдавать или нет. А английского, что бы осознать это, не хватает.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain вот почитайте насчет "где отдавать данные, а где нет". Тут проблема слегка не на серверной стороне. На серверной стороне такого механизма нет, пришел запрос - держи ответ. Фильтрация делается людьми, руками, в коде либо в конфигах сервера, тут масса вариантов как ограничить доступ

Comment: @Darth спасибо сейчас гляну )